# Retrieving own cell number in Windows Phone 7 in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How can I retrieve own cell phone number and IMEI in C# for Windows Phone 7?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if that's possible. Microsoft seems to be gradually turning into an Apple on this one...

Comment: no, there doesn't have to be a way. A phone may not even have a SIM card in it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not currently accessible information.

For a list of what device information you have access to, check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941122(v=VS.92).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to get the own cell number in Windows Phone.