# How do I find the number assigned to a phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How do i get own number information from windows phone 7? Is there a way to include unmanaged code into the application to retrieve own number

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving own cell number in Windows Phone 7 in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099932/retrieving-own-cell-number-in-windows-phone-7-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not a way to hide unmanaged code.  There was a way to get some undocumented access to the OS prior to Mango, but that has been resolved with Mango.