# Sim number and serial number in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

How can i fetch SIM number or phone serial number in windows phone 7? In Android I use this code and it works:

```
    / Get the SIM country ISO code
    String simCountry = telephonyManager.getSimCountryIso();
    // Get the operator code of the active SIM (MCC + MNC)
    String simOperatorCode = telephonyManager.getSimOperator();
    // Get the name of the SIM operator
    String simOperatorName = telephonyManager.getSimOperatorName();
    // -- Requires READ_PHONE_STATE uses-permission --
    // Get the SIM’s serial number
    String simSerial = telephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber();
```

Comment: code is:

/ Get the SIM country ISO code
        String simCountry = telephonyManager.getSimCountryIso();
        // Get the operator code of the active SIM (MCC + MNC)
        String simOperatorCode = telephonyManager.getSimOperator();
        // Get the name of the SIM operator
        String simOperatorName = telephonyManager.getSimOperatorName();
        // -- Requires READ_PHONE_STATE uses-permission --
        // Get the SIM’s serial number
        String simSerial = telephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber();

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find the number assigned to a phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339095/how-do-i-find-the-number-assigned-to-a-phone)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving own cell number in Windows Phone 7 in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099932/retrieving-own-cell-number-in-windows-phone-7-in-c)

Comment: Yes this is for Android, i wanna exactly this one for WP7 - Windows Phone 7

Answer (score 3):

There is no API available for 3rd party developers to access the phone or SIM number.